# Is it possible to make chkdisk print the files that are affected?

Tags: windows

Can chkdisk be made to display the files that are affected?

Comment: No.
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt and run `chkdsk /?`

Or even press the <kbd>F1</kbd> key and search for `chkdsk`. The `/?` provides the current argument list for the binary.

The search for the phrase "windows chkdsk files affected" returned this result at the top: [Is there a list of what the output(s) of CHKDSK answers mean - Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/is-there-a-list-of-what-the-outputs-of-chkdsk/c324d39e-c86d-495a-a83e-8c620bebe54d)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `/v` flag when you run chkdsk. This will use the verbose output mode, and tell you what records are affected (note that chkdsk does not affect files per say, it fixes the MFT)